# MVC Action giving IIS access denied error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a very strange issue that is affecting only one of my actions in a specific controller.

All other actions in this controller post just fine, but when I post the view of one particular action I get the error:

> HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action You do not have permission to
>   view this directory or page.

This confuses me as all views post in a similar fashion and use the same web.config files.

My view:

```
<form action="/Admin/EditMenus" method="Post" class="form-horizontal">
....standard form controls in here.....
</form>
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditMenus(string mondayWeek1RegularDescription,
            string mondayWeek1RegularCost,
            string mondayWeek1VegetarianDescription,
            string mondayWeek1VegetarianCost,
            string mondayWeek1NocarbDescription,
            string mondayWeek1NocarbCost,
            string mondayWeek1KiddiesDescription,
            string mondayWeek1KiddiesCost,
            string tuesdayWeek1RegularDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek1RegularCost,
            string tuesdayWeek1VegetarianDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek1VegetarianCost,
            string tuesdayWeek1NocarbDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek1NocarbCost,
            string tuesdayWeek1KiddiesDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek1KiddiesCost,
            string wednesdayWeek1RegularDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek1RegularCost,
            string wednesdayWeek1VegetarianDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek1VegetarianCost,
            string wednesdayWeek1NocarbDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek1NocarbCost,
            string wednesdayWeek1KiddiesDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek1KiddiesCost,
            string thursdayWeek1RegularDescription,
            string thursdayWeek1RegularCost,
            string thursdayWeek1VegetarianDescription,
            string thursdayWeek1VegetarianCost,
            string thursdayWeek1NocarbDescription,
            string thursdayWeek1NocarbCost,
            string thursdayWeek1KiddiesDescription,
            string thursdayWeek1KiddiesCost,
            string fridayWeek1RegularDescription,
            string fridayWeek1RegularCost,
            string fridayWeek1VegetarianDescription,
            string fridayWeek1VegetarianCost,
            string fridayWeek1NocarbDescription,
            string fridayWeek1NocarbCost,
            string fridayWeek1KiddiesDescription,
            string fridayWeek1KiddiesCost,
            string mondayWeek2RegularDescription,
            string mondayWeek2RegularCost,
            string mondayWeek2VegetarianDescription,
            string mondayWeek2VegetarianCost,
            string mondayWeek2NocarbDescription,
            string mondayWeek2NocarbCost,
            string mondayWeek2KiddiesDescription,
            string mondayWeek2KiddiesCost,
            string tuesdayWeek2RegularDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek2RegularCost,
            string tuesdayWeek2VegetarianDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek2VegetarianCost,
            string tuesdayWeek2NocarbDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek2NocarbCost,
            string tuesdayWeek2KiddiesDescription,
            string tuesdayWeek2KiddiesCost,
            string wednesdayWeek2RegularDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek2RegularCost,
            string wednesdayWeek2VegetarianDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek2VegetarianCost,
            string wednesdayWeek2NocarbDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek2NocarbCost,
            string wednesdayWeek2KiddiesDescription,
            string wednesdayWeek2KiddiesCost,
            string thursdayWeek2RegularDescription,
            string thursdayWeek2RegularCost,
            string thursdayWeek2VegetarianDescription,
            string thursdayWeek2VegetarianCost,
            string thursdayWeek2NocarbDescription,
            string thursdayWeek2NocarbCost,
            string thursdayWeek2KiddiesDescription,
            string thursdayWeek2KiddiesCost,
            string fridayWeek2RegularDescription,
            string fridayWeek2RegularCost,
            string fridayWeek2VegetarianDescription,
            string fridayWeek2VegetarianCost,
            string fridayWeek2NocarbDescription,
            string fridayWeek2NocarbCost,
            string fridayWeek2KiddiesDescription,
            string fridayWeek2KiddiesCost,
            string week1StartDate,
            string week2StartDate,
            string orderBy,
            string menuStart,
            string menuEnd
            ){
...standard control posting to model...
return View();
}
```

The error to me says it must be IIS related but the fact that other actions in the same controller work just fine and it's just this one tells me something else....Like I said this works locally fine but on server gives the error.

Comment: what's happened in controller? Could be that pool user just don't have permission to some folder.

Comment: Seriously man.. view models ....

Comment: @Sippy models are overrated :)

Comment: You maintain that then!

Comment: Whatever you do, learn view models. This is horrendous

Comment: Oh wow. What madness is that?! I feel sick/dirty/smelly just looking at it...

Comment: LOL alright will look into view models.  Doesn't make sense to me why one action can post fine to the "Admin" controller but another action in same controller can't? Suggestions?

Comment: See if your IIS logs show anything more specific, they should do. I'm guessing ModSecurity is an external plugin, it looks like it's misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sippy suggested the issue was with rules in ModSecurity that the hosting company did not configure correctly.

Thanks again.

I also learnt about view models today lol

Answer (score 6):

Go to the `web.config`  by FTP and  write the following line in `web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf" />
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem. And i solved it delete 2 files (ModSecurity ISS (32bits) and ModSecurity ISS (64bits)) in the Moduls section of apropiriate site in ISS.