# HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action

Tags: asp.net

I m creating a code in which based on query string the URL is changing when no values are supplied in URL everything is working fine but as i supply values to URL it shows Error **HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action**
Kindly suggest some solution
also the same is working fine in local problem occurs when i upload my webpage to server

Comment: You need to explain your problem in more detail. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @JoelLee My Page URL is abc.com/Result.aspx?type=5&city=city and it is working fine but as i append my url with QueryString abc.com/Result.aspx?type=5&city=City&|=%20and%20Vendor_Value_Table.Feature_ID=37%20and%20Value_Text%20like%20%27%feature%20option%%27 it gives me Error HTTP Error 403.0 - ModSecurity Action
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: Umm... abc.com is owned by American Broadcasting Company (ABC). You are having a problem when you "upload to server". Are you telling me you work for ABC?

Comment: @Joel Lee abc.com is not American Broadcasting Company i m using an example you can take xyz if you want

Comment: It is impossible to for anyone to say what is wrong without looking at the server side code, to find out where the 403 response is coming from.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011704/http-error-403-0-modsecurity-action-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-d

Comment: these examples are not worth it @JoelLee its working fine in Local Server i told u problem occurs when i upload

Comment: @user1870546 - The answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056018/463139 worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but posting the answer so that it can be helpful for others. ModSecurity is an open source, cross-platform web application firewall (WAF) module.
https://modsecurity.org/about.html

So whenever you see the 403 (ModSecurity Action), this means that the mod security firewall has blocked the request. The probable cause could be vulnerable data present in the posted data, or the it could be because of the URL posted as parameter or it could be JavaScript.

In above case, the ModSecurity might have deemed the input as SQL Injection attack and hence may have blocked it. If you look into the logs of the firewall it may give you the detailed explanation.

In my case, I was passing URL as query parameter in the request hence it was returning 403.